# Sql Server Replication Errror: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, database-replication

Where I work there are 2 SQL server 2008 that are linked servers and have a database that has a replication.
A few month ago we have migrated our AD DC to a new one in order to be part of the company forest.
I had to reinitialize the replication due to a new developer adding a SP on subscription side. When I reinitialized with new snapshot the following error occurred:

View Synchronization status : *Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.*

I’ve done the following actions and checks that after all didn’t worked:

Both SQL server agent services are running on the same domain user
I gave the user full access the to the snapshot folder.
I checked the old and new domain for the user settings and attributes in case there is something the might help. Everything was the same.
Added the user/Login to Publication access list.
Recreate the SQL user/login roles and mapping of the old user.
Added the user/login to Linked server – Local server login to remote server login just as it was on the old user.

If you have an idea what I should do or where I should look for it would be great.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. The snapshot seems to be generate. View Snapshot Agent status : *[100%] A snapshot of 1646 article(s) was generated.* 
But I'm not sure if the replication is working properly.

Comment: check this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/08/10/sql-linked-server-query-failed-with-login-failed-for-user/

Comment: see ,if you are getting kerberos on both the servers

Comment: Hi, I check Kerberos and delegation everything seems to be fine. I found that there are credentials for the user that haven't been changed since we changed the Domain. do you think this might be related?

Comment: Well it's still a permissions issue

Comment: It turns out that the credentials were not related. The problem was solved after removing the subscription and re creating it.